# php print callable function

Tags: php, callable

I'm trying to solve a problem :

```
function f($callable_function){
   print_r($callable_function);// doesn't work at all, of course
}

f(function(){echo "hello World"});
```

I get the `Closure Object` element with my print_r function. Is there a way to get :

```
//OUTPUT RESULT
echo "hello World";
```

**EDIT**

The purpose of this is to get the function declaration inside a String (for database later). The f function can be used by any developer so the idea is to make this as simple as possible, that means I don't want the developer to declare his function inside of a String.

Comment: PHP is not JavaScript, you cannot print out source code like that...

Comment: You can only get `hello world` not along with `echo `

Comment: If you want to actually execute the function and get the output from it, then do so, I don't know what you thought you would get by using `print_r` on it.

Comment: I know php doesn't work like javascript but is there a way to get the function declaration into a string, I don't want to execute the function itself.

Comment: Why a function made to dump an array should do something so ?

Comment: I'm just searching a way to get the declaration, the idea is to store the function declaration.

Comment: Is there a goal behind this attemp ?

Comment: You will get better answers if you describe *what* you are trying to *achieve*, instead of describing *how* you fail with a solution you think is correct. Classic XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never closed this question but I have the answer since 2014 :

```
 $reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction($callable);
 $filename = $reflFunc->getFileName()); 
 $startline = $reflFunc->getStartLine(); 
 $endline = $reflFunc->getEndLine();
```

And using `preg_match`, I can extract what I need. (as suggested by
the first answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PHP file as a string and then find the function (the following exemple is a very quick one, it should be improved):

```
function f($callable_function) {
    $f = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    preg_match("#function $callable_function\(.*\)[^\{]*{(.*)}#Us", $f, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}

function a() {
    echo "hello World";
}

f('a');
```

But there is some limitations:

- It can be complicated if you have many PHP files for instance
- My exemple not supports character `{` into the body of the function, but this can be improved by somebody good at regex
- It doesn't work with anonymous callbacks (and maybe with object's method)

Comment: I like this solution, this may be a replacement to my solution, but I would be happy to use anonymous functions. But thank you for you help :-)

Comment: This answer helped a lot : Insted of preg_match function name, I used : 
    $reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction($callable);
    $file = file_get_contents($reflFunc->getFileName());
    $reflFunc->getStartLine();
    $reflFunc->getEndLine();

Comment: if the function is declared dynamically (callable sometime is), then this could be long search for right file across the project

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a complete function:

```php
private function getFunctionSourceCode(callable $callable)
{
    $reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction($callable);
    $lines = file($reflFunc->getFileName());
    $slices = array_slice(
        $lines, 
        $start = $reflFunc->getStartLine() - 1, 
        $reflFunc->getEndLine() - $start,
    );
    return implode("<br>\n", $slices);
}
```